# not able to work with two schemas in a model file mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have multiple schemas in a single model file, i am exporting that, but in services layer, it says undefined. I followed some other old questions, but not able to make it work. not sure, whats wrong

here are the codes so far.

> this is visas.model.js in models folder

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { toJSON, paginate } = require('./plugins');

const visaSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        visaUid: { type: String, unique: true },
        country: { type: String },
        visaSlug: { type: String, default: null },
        banner: {
            imgid: { type: String, default: null },
            imgurl : { type: String }
        },
        visaType: [
            {
                typeUid: { type: String, default: null, unique: true },
                typeName: { type: String, default: null },
                EmbassyFee: { type: String, default: null },
                b2bserviceFee: { type: String, default: null },
                b2cserviceFee: { type: String, default: null },
                validity: { type: String, default: null },
                physicalPassport: { type: String, default: null },
            }
        ],
        processTime: { type: String, default: null },
        baseCurrency: { type: String, default: null },
        Faqs: [{
            Question: { type: String, default: null },
            Answer: { type: String, default: null },
            ApplyToVisaType: { type: [String], default: null },
            Category: { type: String, default: null }
        }]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

visaSchema.plugin(toJSON);
visaSchema.plugin(paginate);
const Visa = mongoose.model('ttc_Visas', visaSchema);


const VisaDocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    VisaDocId: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        required: true 
    },
    VisaDocName: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
        required: true
    },
    VisaDocRemarks: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    DocType: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

VisaDocumentSchema.plugin(toJSON);
VisaDocumentSchema.plugin(paginate);
const VisaDocuments = mongoose.model('ttc_VisasDocuments', VisaDocumentSchema);

module.exports = {
    Visa: Visa,
    VisaDocuments: VisaDocuments
};
```

> this is visas.service.js inside services folder

```
    const { Visas } = require('../models/visas.model');
const { VisaDocuments } = require('../models/visas.model');

const queryVisas = async (filter, options) => {
    const visas = await Visas.paginate(filter, options);
    return visas;
};

module.exports = {
    queryVisas,
};
```

> i am getting this error,

```
    error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'paginate' of undefined
    at Object.queryVisas (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/services/visas.service.js:10:31)
    at /Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/controllers/visas.controller.js:15:43
    at /Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/src/utils/catchAsync.js:2:19
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
error: GET /v1/visas/getallvisas?api_key=***********&page=1&limit=50 500 - 17.770 ms - message: Cannot read property 'paginate' of undefined
```

Comment: change to Visa { Visas } = require('../models/visas.model')

Comment: I already have this. as you can check in service file.

Comment: it was a typo issue. thanks